# Symfony2 run a service in a background, with possibility of control of execution

Tags: php, symfony, service, command-line-interface, backend

I have implemented a console script in Symfony2, that runs infinitely in the background.
It is responsible for parsing of mailbox and then persist the new email in my database.
I would like to know how I can stop this command from a controller

Is there another solution to my problem I'm interested, because the idea of creating a command does not please me

```
class ImapCommand extends Command {
private $em;

public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->em = $em;
}

protected function configure()
{
    $this->setName('myproject:emailparse')->setDescription('Parse Email');
}

protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    while (true) {
      sleep(60);
      $mailbox = new Mailbox('{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX', 'xxxxxxx@gmail.com', '********', 'c:/');

      $mailsIds = $mailbox->searchMailbox('UNSEEN');

      $mail = $mailbox->getMail($mailsIds[1]);
    //... persist in database
    }
}}
```

and I use this command to run
"php app/console myproject:emailparse"

the email address and password are loaded from the database, I have not put in this code

I want to stop this command from a controllor when the admin decides to change the address mail or the password then restart it

Comment: *the idea of creating a command does not please me* why did you create then as a command in first?

Comment: I have not found another solution

Comment: @ReynierPM, a bit strange question from your side, with sarcasm. He's the new guy, so it's better to be welcome. Ahmed, please describe your CLI script, post some code snippets to understand what you are doing. To stop your script - you may kill the process you just run, or to create some triggers on which the script will react. It depends on your taste and the way you'll implement.

Comment: @Farside I agreed but if you notice when he/she post for first time we had nothing, now question is more clear and any can answer :D